# How to upload a word document using WCF service while maintaining the styling?

Tags: javascript, c#, wcf, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome extension with the feature of uploading a Word document and using a WCF service to get the job done. While the file is getting saved on the server the content of the Word document is getting all messed up. I think it's a problem with the encoding, but I am unsure how to solve it. Any suggestions on how I can fix my code?

WCF Service

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/UploadFile", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string UploadFile( Stream fileStream);

public string UploadFile(Stream fileStream)
{

    try
    {
        string FilePath = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Uploads"), "Test.docx");


        int length = 0;
        using (FileStream writer = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            int readCount;
            var buffer = new byte[8192];
            while ((readCount = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                writer.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                length += readCount;
            }
        }
        return "true";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/error.txt"), ex.StackTrace);
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/error.txt"), "\n" + ex.Message);
        return "false";
    }


}
```

Chrome Extension Upload Function

```
document.getElementById('uploadResume').addEventListener('click', function () {
    const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    const file = fileInput.files[0];
    
    if (file) {
        // Create a FormData object to send the file
        console.log("FIleData\n");
        console.log(file);
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('fileName', file.name);
        formData.append('fileStream', file);
        // Create an XMLHttpRequest object
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // Define the WCF service URL
        const wcfServiceUrl = '';

        // Open a POST request to the WCF service
        xhr.open('POST', wcfServiceUrl, true);

        // Set a callback function to handle the response
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                // Request was successful, handle the response here
                console.log('File upload successful');
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            } else {
                // Request failed, handle errors here
                console.error('File upload failed');
            }
        };
        console.log(formData);
        xhr.send(formData);
    } else {
        console.error('No file selected');
    }
    console.log("Button CLicked");
});
```

Comment: You are making an HTTP Request and the Word document is in the body of the request.  The POST method indicates the request contains body data.  You have two choices 1) Make the Word document a MIME attachment to the body 2) Send the word document in the body.  You can specify the Content-Type=application/msword.  Or you can compress the document using GZIP, or you can convert the document to a Base64string.

Comment: Can you tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Where did you get the code from?  Where do you add the file to the body of the request?  Where do you specify the Content-Type?

Comment: I also agree with the above. But I think the Content-type should be: "application/octet-stream". You can add the following code to your method: **WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";**